# change XML encoding

Tags: xml, asp-classic, character-encoding

in asp not asp.net how to change XML encoding from UTF-16 to UTF-8
my code write xml to string then i use

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
response .write xmlstring
```

but encoding always come UTF-16 and miss some words

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure the `Response` object so it outputs `UTF-8` data:

```
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
```